# Dynamically building an Mongoose aggregate query in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to build a mongoose aggregate query dynamically based on the content of an array variable passed in a POST api call as shown below, yet I am always receiving error **"$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects"** so was wondering if anyone can review my code below please let me know what I might be missing / doing wrong?

```
static search (searchData) {
    let { searchTerm, filterBy } = searchData;
    searchTerm = Utils.escapeRegexSpecialCharacters(searchTerm);

    let filterByElementsLength = filterBy.length; 
    if(filterByElementsLength === 0) {
        query.push({
            $match: { 'bookTitle': new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i') },
        });
    }else if (filterByElementsLength > 0) {            
        query.push({
            $match: { $and: [ 
                { 'bookTitle': new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i') },
                filterBy 
            ] }                
        });
    }
}
```

Taking in consideration that filterBy content is posted as JSON (Application/json) using Postman with the following content example:

```
"filterBy": [{"author": "Michael White" }, { "Price_Less_Than": "100" }],
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, posting it here below:

```
        let matchQry = [];
        matchQry.push({ 'bookTitle': new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i') });

        for(let i = 0; i < filterByElementsLength; i++) {
            matchQry.push(filterBy[i]);             
        }            
        query.push({
            $match: { $and: matchQry }                
        });
```

If anyone think there could be a better solution, please let me know. Thanks for your support